# Encrypted PHP file issue

Tags: php, bash, unix, encryption

I have an php script which is encrypted I think using Zend.  When i run php filename.php, it runs fine although it doesn't when I include it in a bash script.  Does anyone know what could be wrong? I have php installed in  /usr/local/bin/.

Comment: How are you "including it in a bash script"?

Comment: If your commandline php binary is installed in /usr/local, it will likely also look at a different php.ini, which in turn probably doesn't load the same zend extensions as your mod_php version.

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see what php.ini file your command line i running with this:

```
$ php -i | grep 'Configuration File'
```

So then you can either modify that file to load zend optimizer. (look for the zend_extension flag in the php.ini your web server uses)

Or, you can force which php.ini file to use with the -c flag

```
$ php -c /path/to/web-server/php.ini myscript.php
```